# Get the Windows screen saver timeout using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a simple C++ application on windows which check the display turn off time.

After some search I found this function using windows.h

```
int time;
bool check;
check = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, 0, &time, 0);
if (check) {
    cout << "The Screen Saver time is : " << time << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Sorry dude the windows api can't do it" << endl;
}
```

but when I use this code the time is always zero and in my windows setting i set the windows to turn off display on 5 minutes

I tried some solution my self I changed the time type to long long and I got garbage number a very big number, so what I made wrong to get the screen turn off time.

OS: Windows 10

Compiler: Mingw32 and i test with MSVC 2015

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Screen saver timeout*** and ***display power-off timeout*** are two different things.

`SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` returns the ***screen saver timeout*** - the time after which the [Screen Saver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026828/windows-change-your-screen-saver-settings) is activated. If a screen saver was never configured, the value is 0.

The ***display power-off timeout*** is the time after which the power to the screen is cut, and is part of the power profile (and can differ e.g. for battery vs. AC power).

Use [`CallNtPowerInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation) to get the display power-off timeout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <powerbase.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "PowrProf.lib")

int main() {
    SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY powerPolicy;
    DWORD ret;

    ret = CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerPolicyCurrent, nullptr, 0, &powerPolicy, sizeof(powerPolicy));

    if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Display power-off timeout : " << powerPolicy.VideoTimeout << "s \n";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error 0x" << std::hex << ret << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Example output:

```
Display power-off timeout : 600 s
```